# How to remove white space in array values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to remove white space from the array. After "uploads/" there is a space. I am having the array like this

`Array ( [0] => uploads/706.pdf [1] => uploads/ 795.docx [2] => uploads/ 641.docx )`

I need the output like this

```
Array ( [0] => uploads/706.pdf [1] => uploads/795.docx [2] => uploads/641.docx )
```

Comment: You have to use for each loop and use the str_replce function to remove space.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: better find out where this space is coming from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Below loop may be helpful for us.

```
 foreach($array as &$val){
          $data[] = str_replace(' ','',$val);
         }
```

> Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
      $yourArray = ( [0] => uploads/706.pdf [1] => uploads/ 795.docx [2] => 
                  uploads/ 641.docx );
      $newArray = [];
      foreach($yourArray as $val){

           $newArray[]=str_replace(' ', '', $val);
       }
       echo"<pre>";print_r($newArray);
```